# How to add a transient NSIndexPath property to NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I mean to add a property of type `NSIndexPath` to my `NSManagedObject` but it doesn't seem to be one of the recognized property list types. I also mean to make it transient since index paths change depending on the UI, hence I have no reason to save it in the managed document.

I'm thinking of creating two separate `NSNumber` properties called `section` and `row` instead but it'll be much easier if I had an `NSIndexPath` instead. Help?

Comment: You can use a `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to convert objects to data. And then save that to your `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a transformable attribute with no value transformer name.  The default transformer-- `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName`-- takes any class that conforms to the NSCoding protocol and saves it as NSData.

Works for me with `NSIndexPath`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary`.  <strike>The accessors just work... I believe by setting and getting an `id` type, so it's not as typesafe as an `NSIndexSet*` property would be, but it's good enough.</strike>

[edit...]

Err, actually.  I use Mogenerator, which may take care of the issue [mentioned in the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)

> In principle, you don’t have to do anything else. In practice, to suppress compiler warnings you should declare a property for the attribute...

... it's Mogenerator that makes a property of type `id`.  The Apple example creates a property of the specific type in the entity class.